# Not able to select Availability Zones on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an Elastic Beanstalk environment with custom configuration. I was able to change Availability Zones and placement, and I picked them.

After I created the environment, Elastic Beanstalk complained about

```
- Stack named 'awseb-e-**********-stack' aborted operation. Current
  state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
  create: [AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition].

- The EC2 instances failed to communicate with AWS Elastic Beanstalk,
  either because of configuration problems with the VPC or a failed EC2
  instance. Check your VPC configuration and try launching the
  environment again.
```

I wanted to check out the AZs and placements; however, they are disabled

[image: Disabled AZs and Placement in Elastic Beanstalk configuration]

Why is that disabled? Is there a way to enable it? If so, **how**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Elastic Beanstalk with Load Balancer, you need to control Auto Scaling Group under **Configuration** > **Network**.

For example, if you just want to deploy on `us-east-1b`, select a subnet which uses that Availability Zone.